# What is the relationship between boundedness, total boundedness and compactness in topological vector space?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

In our lecture notes, we have that in a topological vector spaces, every compact set is totally bounded and every totally bounded set is bounded but is the converse true?

Comment: No in $\Bbb R$ $(0,1)$ is totally bounded but not compact e.g.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, Is $X=R$ and $F=R$ with usual topology on both here?

Comment: of course, what else. Or any open ball in $\Bbb R^n$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, what about the relationship between total boundedness and bounded sets?

Comment: Boundedness and bounded set?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I mean is every bounded set totally bounded?

Comment: No, the closed unit ball in $\ell^\infy$ is bounded but not totally bounded.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma is the topology on $l^\infty$ here also the usual topology?

Comment: Yes the sup norm induced one.

Answer (score 2):

None of the two implications reverse even in the small class of Banach spaces. (small compared to all TVS's I mean).

Any open ball in $\Bbb R^n$ is totally bounded but not compact.

The closed unit disk $D_1:=\{x\mid \|x\|_\infty\le 1\}$ in $\ell^\infty$ (in ts sup norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$) is bounded (norm-bounded implies TVS-bounded) but not totally bounded (or $D_1$ would be compact which it is not).